# XSLT: <xsl:strip-space> error and omitting some elements from XML output

Tags: xml, xslt

Thanks a lot for your immediate response. The code which you sent did work fine for me, but when we have the below line it throws an error. It works fine when this line is removed.
For this line `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` I am getting the below error

> White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded.
>   Provide the input document as an `XmlReader` instead.

Also, I have one more doubt: what to do if we want to have some child nodes and not all child nodes selected.

For example:

```
<root type="object">
    <items type="array">
        <item type="object">
            <elem1></elem1>
            <elem2></elem2>
            <elem3></elem3>
            <elem4></elem4>
            <elem5></elem5>
            <elem6></elem6>
            <elem7></elem7>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Should be transformed to:

```
<assets>
    <item>
        <elem1></elem1>
        <elem3></elem3>
        <elem6></elem6>
        <elem7></elem7>
    </item>
</assets>
```

Comment: Questions in StackOverflow should really be self-contained, so you should edit your question to include the code you are having trouble with (especially because you have not even provided a link to your previous question). For this particular case though, it would probably help if you showed your C# / VB.Net(?) code which is performing the transformation. Thank you.

Comment: Which code are you referring to? What is the XSLT code?

Comment: I improved the formatting, spelling and clarity of the question. I also changed the title to match the content of the question more appropriately.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XSLT-1.0. It copies all wanted `elemX` elements with `X€[1,3,6,7]` and removes all the other `elemY` elements.
All spaces are removed by `<xsl:strip-space>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <assets>
        <item>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </item>
      </assets>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="elem1|elem3|elem6|elem7" priority="1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(.),'elem')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assets>
    <item>
        <elem1/>
        <elem3/>
        <elem6/>
        <elem7/>
    </item>
</assets>
```